# How do I Convert Typescript Code to React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm in the process of implementing [Andreas Aeschlimann's Gabor](https://github.com/andreas-aeschlimann/gabor) filter written in Angular in a React app. I need to convert some Typescript function calls over to React jsx. Here is the original TS code:

```
async gaborConvolution2(f: Float32Array,
                       xi: number,
                       sigma: number,
                       lambda: number,
                       theta: number,
                       amount: number,
                       successCallback: (fConv: Float32Array, event: MessageEvent) => void,
                       errorCallback: (event: ErrorEvent) => void) {

    // Create a new worker
    const backgroundWorker: Worker = new Worker("assets/js/gaborConvolution2.js");

    // The success callback
    backgroundWorker.onmessage = (event: MessageEvent) => {
        backgroundWorker.terminate();
        successCallback(event.data.fConv, event);
    };

    // The error callback
    backgroundWorker.onerror = (event: ErrorEvent) => {
        backgroundWorker.terminate();
        errorCallback(event);
    };

    // Post the data
    backgroundWorker.postMessage({f: f, xi: xi, sigma: sigma, lambda: lambda, theta: theta, amount: amount});

}
```

My jsx implementation is:

```
async gaborConvolution2(f,
        xi,
        sigma,
        lambda,
        theta,
        amount,
        successCallback(fConv, event) => void,
        errorCallback(event) => void) {

        // Create a new worker
        const backgroundWorker = new Worker("assets/js/gaborConvolution2.js");

        // The success callback
        backgroundWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
        backgroundWorker.terminate();
        successCallback(event.data.fConv, event);
        };

        // The error callback
        backgroundWorker.onerror = (event) => {
        backgroundWorker.terminate();
        errorCallback(event);
        };

        // Post the data
        backgroundWorker.postMessage({f: f, xi: xi, sigma: sigma, lambda: lambda, theta: theta, amount: amount});

        }
}
```

The `successCallback(fConv, event) => void,` and `errorCallback(event) => void)` lines in jsx are not correct. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Explain what `successCallback(fConv, event) => void`, as a parameter declaration, means in TypeScript or JavaScript and you'll be well on your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly, you simply need to be declaring a default for each function you will want passed to `gaborConvolution2`, in case you don't receive one. Like so:

```
gaborConvolution2(f,
        xi,
        sigma,
        lambda,
        theta,
        amount,
        successCallback = () => {},
        errorCallback = () => {}, ){
        //do something, call functions, etc...
        }
```

Comment: I think that is the void statement in the TypeScript version but I can't figure out the syntax in jsx.

Comment: set the default like this: `successCallback = () => {}`

Comment: That seems to work for the `successCallback = () => {}` line but VS Code complains about `errorCallback = (event) => void) {}` The closing parenthese ")" is needed. Sorry, I know this shouldn't be this difficult!

Comment: You should follow the same pattern for setting a default for errorCallback: `errorCallback = () => {}`

Comment: Yes, but where do you put the closing ")" for the argument list? Anywhere I put it, VS Code complains about it.

Comment: In this case the line should be `errorCallback = (event) => {}) => {}`

Comment: Not sure what is going on with your code or editor, because that code should have worked. I've edited the post above to show how it should look...and just to clarify, this isn't anything unique to JSX. This is just vanilla JavaScript syntax for setting default parameters for a function.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The comma in the ````errorCallback```` line is not needed but it compiles either way.